# Why does OAuth redirect not work in iOS 13 but it does in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftydropbox

I'm developing my app which should interact with dropbox, download a file, read and write it and then upload it. The problem is that the app works fine in iOS 12 but doesn't work in iOS 13. I think the problem is here because the code is not executed and in the iOS 12 simulator it is.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

this is the code in view controller

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SwiftyDropbox

class viewCon:UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lab: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
        if client == nil { lab.text = "Not logged"} else {lab.text = "Logged"}
    }

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared, controller:self, openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.open(url)})
    }


    @IBAction func download(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

and this is AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        print("init")
        DropboxClientsManager.setupWithAppKey("********")
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print("1")
        if let authResult = DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url as URL) {
            print("2")
            switch authResult {
            case .success(_): //(let token)
                //print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox with token: \(token)")
                print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox.")
            case .cancel:
                print("User canceld OAuth flow.")
            case .error(let error, let description):
                print("Error \(error): \(description)")
            }
        } else {
            print("3")
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

this is my info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>db-*********</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>dbapi-8-emm</string>
        <string>dbapi-2</string>
    </array>
```

I put print("x") to understand if the code was executed and I noticed that in ios12 is all right, in iOS 13 does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check scene delegate openurlcontext method?

Comment: nope, can you be more explicit please?

Comment: func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        for urlContext in URLContexts {
            let url = urlContext.url
            Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
        }
        // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }

Comment: thank you, could you write it an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this func in SceneDelegate

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
      for urlContext in URLContexts {
          let url = urlContext.url

          if let authResult = DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url) {
              switch authResult {
              case .success:
                  print("Success! User is logged into account.")

              case .cancel:
                  print("Authorization flow was manually canceled by user!")
              case .error(_, let description):
                  print("Error: \(description)")
              }
          }

      }
  }
```